# Setting up home network with 2 routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, ip

I have a router that I got from my ISP (Technicolor GCA4233DE) and my own router (Asus DSL-AC87VG) and I’m trying to setup my network in a way that all devices can see each other.

The ISP router has only one PC connected to it right now and the WiFi is disabled.
The Asus router is connected to the ISP’s via the WAN port on it (lan to wan) and configured as a bridge/access point.
[See diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NsgX.jpg)

Now the problem: The devices connected to the Asus router can reach the ISP router and PC but the PC can’t reach anything.
My understanding is that I need to reroute the Asus IP (for example 192.168.0.110) to the other devices but I don’t know how.

What option should I be looking for on the ISP’s router?

Answer (score 1):

Do the following instead (a method used many times).

1. Connect a LAN port (not WAN) on the ASUS router to a LAN port on the ISP router.
2. Log into the ASUS Router and give it a static IP address on the ISP router (so it will not get lost if restarts occur).
3. Turn DHCP OFF on the LAN setup of the ASUS router.

Now all will be on one single network which is what you are trying to achieve.

Another way to do this to maintain the function of the ASUS router is the following (might mean a third device):

Make your ASUS to be the main router off the ISP device and do not use the ISP device at all. Then if you need another router, hook it up as above to the ASUS. This will accomplish both objectives.

Comment: The thing is, a I have a PiHole connected to the Asus and the Asus is configured to use it as the DNS server. If I do as you wrote, I will need to change the DNS settings on each device which is too much.

Comment: Good point but then you cannot get everything on one network because using then WAN port on the ASUS will prevent that.

Comment: Will it work if I ran a second lan cable between the two routers?

Comment: I don't think so. You would need double WAN / LAN fail-over and then even so I do not think you would get the subnets the same.

Comment: I posted an update to help you.